# How to remove multiple trailing newlines after fgets()?

Tags: c, newline, fgets, getchar, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>



int main()
{

int upper=0;
int digit=0;
int i=0;


char s[30];
char c;

printf("Enter sentence: ");
fgets(s, 30, stdin);

//s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';


while(c=getchar() && c!='\n')
{

  c = s[i];

     if(isupper(c))
    {
        upper++;
    }

     if(isdigit(c))
    {
        digit++;
    }


  i++;
}

printf("Number of upper case letters............... %d", upper);
printf("\n");
printf("Number of digits........................... %d", digit);
printf("\n");


printf("Program done. ");





return 0;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

---

How can I remove the **multiple newlines** after the fgets() ?
I have tried implementing the following line after fgets()

**s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';**

but this does not work and my program does not run through all the code.

Without the code ----->   s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';

---

Here is the Output:

```
Enter sentence: Whats UP 1234















Number of upper case letters............... 3
Number of digits........................... 4
Program done.
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 9.340 s
Press any key to continue.
```

---

As you can see my program is able to run however I have to press **enter multiple times** and there is a lot of newlines
and then at the very end the program runs the last bit of code.

The program is suppose to count the number of upper case letters and digits in the string 
entered. Can someone please explain why this is happening ?

Comment: Remove that `getchar` stuff. Basically it means you have to press **enter multiple times** to just see your output. I have no idea what you believe it would add to your program.

Comment: Thank you! that fixed the issue.

Comment: @JonSnow If you fixed the issue, please answer or delete your question, to help future readers of your post with the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Jongware:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>



 int main()
 {

int upper=0;
int digit=0;
int i=0;


char s[30];
char c;

printf("Enter sentence: ");
fgets(s, 30, stdin);

//correction: getchar() has been removed from the while condition.
while( c!='\n')
{

 c = s[i];

  if(isupper(c))
 {
    upper++;
 }

 if(isdigit(c))
{
    digit++;
}


i++;
}

printf("Number of upper case letters............... %d", upper);
printf("\n");
printf("Number of digits........................... %d", digit);
printf("\n");




return 0;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: 1) `char c;  ... while( c!='\n')` wrongly attempts to test `c` without ever assigning `c` a value.  2) Minor: `isupper(c)/isdigit(c)` is not well defined should `c` contain a negative value.  Better to use `isupper((unsigned char) c)`  3) Should `s` not contain `'\n'` due to `30` or `EOF`, `while` loop access outside `s[30]`.